# Multitenancy and memcache namespace in PHP on GAE

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Is it possible to set namespaces in memcache when using PHP on Google App Engine?

I have a project that is successfully using different databases according to the hostname (e.g., sub1-dot-myapp.appspot.com vs sub2-dot-myapp.appspot.com), but the visible results are mixed due to memcache objects being served across hostnames and instances. If I can assign the hostname as a namespace, or even a key prefix, that should fix it, but I can't find a way to do this in the PHP runtime.

Comment: I am not familiar with GAE, but I assume google must have some way of delineating keys between accounts, if not running separate instances of memcached, so if you can't figure anything else out you can try that

Answer (score 2):

No, because the memcache implementation in App Engine follows the standard memcache/memcached APIs that are part of PHP, which do not support namespaces.

Seems like a good feature request, you can add it [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request).